# Drupal: unable to set labels for x axis using Charts module

Tags: charts, drupal-7, google-visualization

I want to create a line chart displaying changes in share price over the time using Drupal Charts 7.x-2.0-rc1 API and Google Charts as a library. I tried the following code and populated the chart with some random values:

```
$chart = array(
    '#type' => 'chart',
    '#chart_type' => 'line',
    '#chart_library' => 'google',
    '#title' => t(''),
    '#legend' => FALSE,
    '#colors' => array('FF6600'),
    '#width' => 480,
    '#height' => 240,
    '#data_labels' => TRUE,
    '#raw_options' => array(
        'vAxis' => array(
            'viewWindowMode' => 'explicit',
            'viewWindow' => array(
                'min' => 1,
            ),
        ),
        'hAxis' => array(
            'showTextEvery' => 20
        )
    ),
);

$data = array();
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $data[$i] = array(date('H:i', strtotime("+$i minute")), (rand(5, 10) / 10) * 6);
}

$chart['price'] = array(
    '#type' => 'chart_data',
    '#title' => t('Share price'),
    '#show_in_legend' => FALSE,
    '#data' => $data,
    '#decimal_count' => 2,
);

$shareChart['chart'] = $chart;

return drupal_render($shareChart);
```

I get the following output:
[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BCS8e.jpg)

I want the x axis to display only cerain labels (in this example interval of 20 minutes) but 'showTextEvery' option doesn't work. Any ideas why? Maybe there is another way to achive that?

Comment: Have you checked the Drupal settings object in the generated page? That will allow you to check if the module is passing the variables through correctly (or at least as you expect).

Comment: not sure what you mean as I've been using Drupal for two days now but as I wrote in a comment below: _I've inspected the page with FireBug and I can see my custom options for vAxis passed to html but not for hAxis (tried sth simple like textStyle) so I think the problem lies somewhere in my chart configuration or Drupal's Chart module_

Answer (score 0):

date/time values on the `hAxis` result in a *continuous* axis

`'showTextEvery'` only works for a *discrete* axis, resulting from string values

see [discrete vs continuous](https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/customizing_axes#discrete-vs-continuous)

as such, you would need to provide your own `ticks`

maybe try something like this, generate the `data`, along with the `ticks`, first...

```
$data = array();
$ticks = array();
$x = 0;
for ($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $data[$i] = array(date('H:i', strtotime("+$i minute")), (rand(5, 10) / 10) * 6);
    if ($i % 20 == 0) {
        $ticks[$x] = date('H:i', strtotime("+$i minute"));
        $x++;
    }
}
```

then in the chart definition...

```
$chart = array(
    'hAxis' => array(
        'ticks' => $ticks
    )
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this doesn't solve the problem, labels are exactly the same as they were before; I've read the Google documentation and tried both `ticks` and `showTextEvery`, none of them works, strange because when I set `ticks` for the `vAxis` labels are displayed as I want them; I've inspected the page with FireBug and I can see my custom options for `vAxis` passed to html but not for `hAxis` (tried sth simple like `textStyle`) so I think the problem lies somewhere in my chart configuration or Drupal's Chart module; btw, it's the first time when I'm using Drupal

Comment: not following, you say _tried both ticks and showTextEvery, none of them works_ but then you say _when I set ticks for the vAxis labels are displayed as I want them_ -- last part sounds like it works -- regardless `showTextEvery` will not work here because neither axis has string values, `ticks` should work on either axis -- but you have to supply the values you want...

Comment: and sorry for mistaking x and y axes, I've edited the question; nevertheless my problem and your solution still apply `hAxis`

Comment: none of them works for `hAxis` but I'm able to set `ticks` for `vAxis`